# Reading an empty NFC tag

Tags: android, nfc

does anyone have any idea how to write code to read an empty NFC tag? What type of intent-filter do i need to use to read an empty tag? I will appreciate if anyone can provide some sample codes. i'm using Ultralight C tags.

Comment: refer this link      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546932/how-to-read-and-write-android-nfc-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MIFARE Ultralight tags can be accessed using the [`MifareUltralight`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/MifareUltralight.html) class. More specifically using the `readPages()` method, see the example code at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#read-write

Add a tech list reference to your manifest, as explained in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#tech-disc

In the `nfc_tech_filter.xml` file (stored in the sub-directory `res/xml`) you put:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
  <tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
</tech-list>
```