# How to properly read nfc tag

Tags: android, nfc

I correctly set up NFC environment:

- tech filter

  ```
  <resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
      <tech-list>
         <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
         <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
      </tech-list>
  </resources>
  ```
- in the manifest

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" />

  <activity android:name=".ui.ScanActivity">

          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          </intent-filter>

          <meta-data
              android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
              android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
  </activity>
  ```
- code (Activity, some time after it's created by reading nfc tag)

  ```
  Intent intent = getIntent();

  if (intent != null) {
      String action = intent.getAction();
          if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
              Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
  ```

That's it, rawMsgs is always null, although I have an app on my phone that reads the same tag perfectly, showing data that tag contains.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: Does your tag contain an NDEF message? If `EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES` is null, this typically means that there is no NDEF message on the tag.

Comment: And your tech filter contains android.nfc.tech.Ndef or empty?

Comment: Edited question. Turned out my tag does not contain NDEF's, but I also have another tag that I cannot parse and that definetely contains messages, because another app reads it and shows some data from it.

Comment: Are you sure they are NDEF messages that the other application is reading though? You can easily write an application that reads/writes/shows non-NDEF data if you wish, so just because another application reads some sort of data from the tag doesn't necessarily mean it's reading NDEF data.

Answer (score 2):

There are various types of nfc tags (eg. Mifare Ultralight , Mifare Ultralight C , Mifare Classic , felica...) . Each tags has different Memory size and reading procedure. For Example : Mifare Ultralight has 64 byte but mifare Classic 1k contains 1 kilobytes memory. To read data from mifare ultralight no need extra authentication but Mifare classic needs Authentication. When you get New Intent You can parse it to get tag info:
First of all you have to initialize the NFC adapter and define Pending Intent in onCreate callback:

```
 NfcAdapter mAdapter;
PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);      

    if (mAdapter == null) {
        //nfc not support your device.
        return;
    }
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
            getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
```

In onResume() Call back enable the Foreground Dispatch to detect NFC intent.

```
mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, null, null);
```

In onPause() callback you have to disable the forground dispatch:

```
if (mAdapter != null) {
    mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}
```

In onNewIntent() call back method you will get the new Nfc Intent. After getting The Intent , you have to parse the intent to detect the card:

```
 @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){    
    getTagInfo(intent)
     }

private void getTagInfo(Intent intent) {
    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    }
```

Here You have The Tag . To know Exact tag type Here is [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28565383/3073945)
And Full project is in [my Github Repo](https://github.com/mesuk08/NFC-UTILS)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding intent-filters for NDEF_DISCOVERED and TAG_DISCOVERED in your manifest. And android.nfc.tech.Ndef in your tech filter.