# Reading Data from NFC Tag

Tags: android, nfc

Hi I am developing an app for reading and writing data to NFC Tag. I am having problem in reading data from NFC Tag. When I try to read data my application crashes for first time and again when I scan the Tag for the second time the app reads the data.
Please help me out on this issue. Here is my code.
Thanks in advance.

```
public class Read extends Activity {

    Tag detectedTag;
    TextView txtType,txtSize,txtWrite,txtRead;
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    IntentFilter[] readTagFilters;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.read);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);

         nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
         detectedTag =getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        txtType  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtType);
        txtSize  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtsize);
        txtWrite = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtwrite);
        txtRead  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_read);

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, 
                new Intent(this,getClass()).
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

        IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
        IntentFilter filter2     = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        readTagFilters = new IntentFilter[]{tagDetected,filter2};

    }

    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

        if(getIntent().getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)){
            detectedTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

            readFromTag(getIntent());
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, readTagFilters, null);
    }


    public void readFromTag(Intent intent){

        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(detectedTag);


        try{
            ndef.connect();

            txtType.setText(ndef.getType().toString());
            txtSize.setText(String.valueOf(ndef.getMaxSize()));
            txtWrite.setText(ndef.isWritable() ? "True" : "False");
            Parcelable[] messages = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);

            if (messages != null) {
                NdefMessage[] ndefMessages = new NdefMessage[messages.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                    ndefMessages[i] = (NdefMessage) messages[i];
                }
            NdefRecord record = ndefMessages[0].getRecords()[0];

            byte[] payload = record.getPayload();
            String text = new String(payload);
            txtRead.setText(text);


            ndef.close();

        }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Read From Tag.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you show the output of logcat?

Comment: i am testing the app on real device....

Comment: Yes, of course (the emulator does not support NFC). Normally, on Android devices, logcat output is available, see http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

Comment: Hi....When I am trying to read data i need to scan the tag twice. Once to launch the application and another time for application to read data. What should I do so that the application can read data as soon as I scan the tag for the first time. Waiting for your reply. Thank You

Comment: great one, check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45773087/5733853

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only line missing in onNewIntent() Method was
setIntent(intent);
I added it and the code is running fine.

Comment: you might want to check out the boilerplate in found in http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/