# build NFC reader in android application

Tags: android, android-manifest, nfc

i cant find simple resource to read an NFC Tag. I have looked at the sample code, in the SDK manager but when i run it, it doesn't read my tag.  This is something similar that i am trying to accomplish, here [Reading Data from NFC Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12453658/2159202),  but i don't know exactly what goes in the manifest file???? any help please! this is what i have in my manifest at the moment.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/> 

<activity
        android:name="com.test.nfc.TagsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: did u try adding intent filter in the manifest to call the intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some useful links below.

- http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/getting-started-nfc-android
- http://www.tappednfc.com/wp-content/uploads/TAPPED-NFCDeveloperGuide-Part2.pdf
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html
- http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/31/write-hello-world-into-a-nfc-tag-with-a/

May those help you.

Comment: Thank you. i got it working. the second link was the most helpful, some really great tutorials there.