# Read NFC tag using Broadcast receiver in Android

Tags: android, tags, broadcastreceiver, nfc, javacard

I am new to NFC development in android,so i have created application which detects the NFC tag and read and write Tags.So i used NfcAdapter to detect extra Tag..Using this tag i have used **android.nfc.tech.IsoDep** and using that i send APDU data to the java card.(Jcop 31/36)so now  i need to implement Broadcast receiver which used to detect Tag.(Actually broadcast receiver need detect the tag is discovered every 10 seconds)i found some of article about how to receive Tag from receiver.but these are not clear for me.Can anyone tell me how to start this one(It is better to give some reference)
Thanks
SSV

Comment: are you working with the built in NFC or an external nfc reader ?

Comment: i am working with built in NFC(i am used nexus s for testing)

Comment: may be this can help -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546932/how-to-read-and-write-android-nfc-tags

Comment: Thanks kndroid. i know the how read NFC tag.but i need to integrated to broadcast receiver.

Comment: ok sorry, i guess i am not clear about your question. Can you plz edit your question and be more specific? that will help you to find better answer. If possible write some code sample where you are not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

the only way i figured out was polling the isconnected method in a separate thread. i tried to receive the intent nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED in a receiver but it didn't work, you can use an activity with the singletop launchmode instead