# Can't send APDU to Java Card

Tags: android

I have a JavaCard with applet which returns simple "HelloWorld". Now I'm trying to send APDU to card from my smartphone.

Basing on Sajedul's respone from here: [How to read and write Android NFC tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546932/how-to-read-and-write-android-nfc-tags) I wrote something like this

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
NfcAdapter mAdapter;
PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
Tag tag;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    if(mAdapter != null){
        mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    getTagInfo(intent);
}

private void getTagInfo(Intent intent){
    tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
}

public void doWork(View view) throws IOException {
    Tag tagFromIntent = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);  

    IsoDep isoDep = IsoDep.get(tagFromIntent);
     isoDep.connect();

    byte[] SELECT = { 
        (byte) 0x00, // CLA = 00 (first interindustry command set)
        (byte) 0xA4, // INS = A4 (SELECT)
        (byte) 0x04, // P1  = 04 (select file by DF name)
        (byte) 0x0C, // P2  = 0C (first or only file; no FCI)
        (byte) 0x06, // Lc  = 6  (data/AID has 6 bytes)
        (byte) 0x31, (byte) 0x35,(byte) 0x38,(byte) 0x34,(byte) 0x35,(byte) 0x46 // AID = 15845F
    };

    byte[] result = isoDep.transceive(SELECT);

}
}
```

But after instllation on phone, app crashes.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.korek.moja/com.example.korek.moja.MainActivity}: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.korek.moja/com.example.korek.moja.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onResume()
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2966)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.korek.moja/com.example.korek.moja.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onResume()
            at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5452)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2922)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2966)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Even before applying Sajedul's tips app was crashing on click. What to do to get it working?
I'm using SGS4, AndroidStudio and 14443-4b card.

EDIT
I've changed my code a bit. Now it's not crashing. I cleaned doWork() method and move its content to onNewIntent method

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    getTagInfo(intent);
    Log.i("tag", tag.toString());
    IsoDep isoDep = IsoDep.get(tag);
    try {
        isoDep.connect();

        isoDep.setTimeout(150);
        byte[] SELECT = new byte[]{(byte)0x00,(byte)0xA4,(byte)0x04,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x07,(byte)0xA0,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x12,(byte)0x01};
        byte[] result = isoDep.transceive(SELECT);
        String a = Integer.toHexString(result[0]);
        String b = Integer.toHexString(result[1]);
        Log.i("len", a);
        Log.i("len", b);

        byte[] INPUT = new byte[]{(byte)0x80,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x0A,(byte)0x48,(byte)0x65,(byte)0x6c,(byte)0x6c,(byte)0x6f,(byte)0x57,(byte)0x6f,(byte)0x72,(byte)0x6c,(byte)0x64,(byte)0xFF};
        result = isoDep.transceive(INPUT);
        a = Integer.toHexString(result[0]);
        b = Integer.toHexString(result[1]);
        Log.i("len", a);
        Log.i("len", b);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but my response is 69 ffffff85. What is this? Where should I look for error?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you haven't tried code below?

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SW=0x6985 means that your card is locked or the keys that you use for authentication are not correct.